# SQL for nested WITH CLAUSE - RESULTS OFFSET in Oracle 19c

Tags: oracle19c, with-clause

Please suggest a way to implement nesting of (temp - results - select) as shown below?

I see that oracle 19c does not allow nesting of WITH clause.

```sql
with temp2 as   
(   
    with temp1 as
    (
        __
        __
    ),
    results(..fields..) as
    (
        select ..<calc part>.. from temp1, results where __
    )   
    select ..<calc part>.. from temp1 join results where __
    
),
results(..fields..) as
(
    select ..<calc part>.. from temp2, results where __
)   
select ..<calc part>.. from temp2 join results where __
```

For instance:

**[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a75809eaaaa38c5ded9b6a16bef4aa1c)**

I need to calculate CALC3 in similar recursive way as of CALC

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST ( DT DATE, NAME VARCHAR2(10), VALUE NUMBER(10,3));

insert into TEST values ( to_date( '01-jan-2021'), 'apple', 198.95 );
insert into TEST values ( to_date( '02-jan-2021'), 'apple', 6.15 );
insert into TEST values ( to_date( '03-jan-2021'), 'apple', 4.65 );
insert into TEST values ( to_date( '06-jan-2021'), 'apple', 20.85 );
insert into TEST values ( to_date( '01-jan-2021'), 'banana', 80.5 );
insert into TEST values ( to_date( '02-jan-2021'), 'banana', 9.5 );
insert into TEST values ( to_date( '03-jan-2021'), 'banana', 31.65 );

--Existing working code - 

with t as
 ( select
     test.*,
     row_number() over ( partition by name order by dt ) as seq
   from test
 ),
 results(name, dt, value, calc ,seq) as
 (
   select name, dt, value, value/5 calc, seq
   from t
   where seq = 1
   union all
   select t.name, t.dt, t.value, ( 4 * results.calc + t.value ) / 5, t.seq
   from t, results
   where t.seq - 1 = results.seq
   and  t.name = results.name
 )
 select results.*, calc*3 as calc2  -- Some xyz complex logic as calc2
 from results
 order by name, seq;
```

**Desired output:**

CALC3 - grouped by name and dt -

`((CALC3 of prev day record * 4) + CALC2 of current record )/ 5`

```sql
i.e for APPLE 
for 1-jan-21, CALC = ((0*4)+119.37)/5 = 23.87 -------> since it is 1st record, have taken 0 as CALC3 of prev day record
for 2-jan-21, CALC = ((23.87*4)+99.19)/5= 115.33 -----> prev CALC3 is considered from 1-jan-21 - 23.87 and 99.19 from current row
for 3-jan-21, CALC = ((115.33*4)+82.14)/5= 477.76 and so on

For BANANA
1-jan-21, CALC = ((0*4)+48.30)/5=9.66
1-jan-21, CALC = ((9.66*4)+44.34)/5=47.51 
etc
```

[image]

Comment: `((9.66*4)+44.34)/5` does not equal `47.51`, it is `16.596`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to, you can just do it all in one level:

```sql
with temp1(...fields...) as
(
    __
    __
    __
),
results1(...fields...) as
(
  select ...<calc part>... from temp1 where __
),
temp2( ...fields...) as   
(   
    select ...<calc part>... from temp1 join results1 where __
),
results2(...fields...) as
(
    select ...<calc part>... from temp2 where __
)   
select ...<calc part>... from temp2 join results2 where __
```

---

For your actual problem, you can use a `MODEL` clause:

```sql
SELECT dt,
       name,
       amount,
       calc,
       seq,
       calc2,
       calc3
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY dt) AS seq
  FROM   test t
)
MODEL
  PARTITION BY (name)
  DIMENSION BY (seq)
  MEASURES ( dt, amount, 0 AS calc, 0 AS calc2, 0 as calc3)
  RULES (
    calc[1] = amount[1]/5,
    calc[seq>1] = (amount[cv(seq)] + 4*calc[cv(seq)-1])/5,
    calc2[seq] = 3*calc[cv(seq)],
    calc3[1] = calc2[1]/5,
    calc3[seq>1] = (calc2[cv(seq)] + 4*calc3[cv(seq)-1])/5
  )
```

Which outputs:

> | DT | NAME | AMOUNT | CALC | SEQ | CALC2 | CALC3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 01-JAN-21 | banana | 80.5 | 16.1 | 1 | 48.3 | 9.66 |
> | 02-JAN-21 | banana | 9.5 | 14.78 | 2 | 44.34 | 16.596 |
> | 03-JAN-21 | banana | 31.65 | 18.154 | 3 | 54.462 | 24.1692 |
> | 01-JAN-21 | apple | 198.95 | 39.79 | 1 | 119.37 | 23.874 |
> | 02-JAN-21 | apple | 6.15 | 33.062 | 2 | 99.186 | 38.9364 |
> | 03-JAN-21 | apple | 4.65 | 27.3796 | 3 | 82.1388 | 47.57688 |
> | 06-JAN-21 | apple | 20.85 | 26.07368 | 4 | 78.22104 | 53.705712 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fcbcfd302fc6c49f20687e87d0dc34c6)*

Comment: Here, I need to  use the result set of 
"select ...<calc part>... from temp1 join results1 where __" 
in temp2 and in turn results2.
where can I implement that?

Comment: @Divya Add in another subquery before `temp2` and put it in there and then use that in `temp2` and `results`. However, you are asking a generic question; if you want a concrete answer that we can test then you will need to give us a [MRE] complete with tables, sample data and expected results.

Comment: @Divya Updated with a simpler solution.

Comment: @MTO This is quite simpler! Thanks for the solution :)